# converting string to filetime

Tags: c++

What is the fastest way to convert a string of the form ""1997-01-08 03:04:01:463"
to filetime?
Is there a function which does that?

Comment: Do you mean a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you are talking about a Windows FILETIME, which contains the number of 100 nanosec ticks since 1/1/1600.

1. Use sscanf() or a std::istringstream to parse the string into its components.
   and populate a SYSTEMTIME struct
2. Use SystemTimeToFileTime() to convert to a FILETIME

e.g.

```
FILETIME DecodeTime(const std::string &sTime)
{
    std::istringstream istr(sTime);
    SYSTEMTIME st = { 0 };
    FILETIME ft = { 0 };

    istr >> st.wYear;
    istr.ignore(1, '-');
    istr >> st.wMonth;
    istr.ignore(1, '-');
    istr >> st.wDay;
    istr.ignore(1, ' ');
    istr >> st.wHour;
    istr.ignore(1, ':');
    istr >> st.wMinute;
    istr.ignore(1, ':');
    istr >> st.wSecond;
    istr.ignore(1, '.');
    istr >> st.wMilliseconds;

    // Do validation that istr has no errors and all fields 
    // are in sensible ranges
    // ...

    ::SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
    return ft;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILETIME ft = DecodeTime("1997-01-08 03:04:01.463");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned filetimes i supposed you refer to Windows since *nix doesn't differentiate between file times and system times like Windows does([FILETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28VS.85%29.aspx) vs. [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Unfortunately in either cases you are out of luck since there are no shortcuts to converting such a string to either a `FILETIME` structure in Windows or `time_t` in *nix using either system or standard C/C++ library calls.

In order to get lucky, you will most likely have to use a wrapper library, for eg. the [Boost library provides such functionality](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on windows, the string looks like SYSTEMTIME and there is a routine called SystemTimeToFileTime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724948.aspx that converts it to a FILETIME. Of course you still have to handle tokenization and integer parsing yourself.